# fbs appID cookies does not exists

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i try to make a connection with Facebook connect but have some errors.

[Further Facebook Login Javascript Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373724/further-facebook-login-javascript-errors)

I have similiar problem with this link.Php $_COOKIE does not find the related cookie

```
Notice: Undefined index: fbs_appID in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpdeneme/index.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: sig in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpdeneme/index.php on line 22

Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phpdeneme/index.php on line 30



<?php


define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'APP_ID');
define('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET','SECRET_ID');


function get_facebook_cookie($appID,$appSecret){
    $args = array();
    parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $appID], '\\"'), $args);


    ksort($args);
    $payload = '';
    foreach($args as $key=>$value){

        if($key != 'sig'){
            $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
        }
    }

    if(md5($payload . $appSecret) != $args['sig'])
            return null;

    return $args;

}

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' . $cookie['access_token']));

?>


    <html>
        <body>
            <?php if($cookie){ ?>

            Welcome <?= $user->name ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
        <fb: login-button></fb:login-button>
        <?php } ?>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script>
        FB.init({appId: '<?= FACEBOOK_APP_ID ?>' , status: true, cookie: true, xfbml:true});
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(response){
           window.location.reload(); 

        });
        </script>

        </body>
         </html>
```

What's wrong ? What's missing ? What fbs cookie not created?

Comment: Um... what about those other errors you posted there?

Comment: Your browser allow that website create the cookie on your PC ?

Answer (score 0):

Your using the old oauth 1.0 format.  You have to use the new format now.

An example from PHP code, that should be close enough, to modify into js with minimal changes:

function get_facebook_cookie()
{
     $CI =& get_instance();
     $app_id = $CI->config->item('facebook_app_id');
     $application_secret = $CI->config->item('facebook_app_secret');
      if(isset($*COOKIE['fbsr*' . $app_id])){
         list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $*COOKIE['fbsr*' . $app_id], 2);

```
     $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
         return null;
     }
     $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload,
     $application_secret, $raw = true);
      if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
          return null;
      }
      $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
     . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&client_secret=" . $application_secret. "&redirect_uri=" . "&code=" . $data['code'];
      $response = file_get_contents($token_url);

      $params = null;
      parse_str($response, $params);
      $data['access_token'] = $params['access_token'];
      return $data;
  }else{
      return null;
 }
```

}

This came from this [useful blog post](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/oauth-20-facebook-changes-and-cookie-problem-in-codeigniter) with some other tidbits about the issue.